# How can I reload my hibernate dependent objects before de validation

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have an Spring controller with code like:

```
@RequestMapping("save")
public String save(@ModelAttribute @Valid Form form, BindingResult result){     

    if( result.hasErrors()){
    [...]
```

My form contains a list of hibernate objects. All have their properties setted. I create an edit HTML form and in the controller I find that all the objects on the ManyToOne relationships is lost. I only have the ID. I could reload data from the database but it is too late for the validation casued by the @valid annotation.

```
public class Form{

@Valid
@NotNull
private List<Item> item;

@NotNull
private Foo foo;
```

[...]

And Item

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
@XmlRootElement
public class Item{

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "dependent", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private Dependent dependent;

    @NotNull
    private Currency currency;
```

How could I set the Dependent and Currency fields before the validation? Is there any alternative to reload data from the database?

(Disclaimer some names have been changes to protect the inocent)

Comment: Try @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)

Comment: I mean for your `Dependent`. [LazyCollectionOption](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-singleassoc-fetching)

Comment: It solved some of my problems but not all. The form may add new Items detached from the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring-Data-JPA you can [register `DomainClassConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#web-domain-class-binding) to do this work for you. In another case you may write such converter by yourself.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of feedback. Spring servers seems to be down.

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to do it:

1. Add to the controller a reference to SmartValidator.

   @Autowired private SmartValidator           validator;
2. Remove the @valid annotation. Reload all ManyToOne tables and call manually the validator.

   @RequestMapping("save")
   public String save(@ModelAttribute Form form, BindingResult result){

   for(Item item : form.getItems()){
       item.setDependant( myDAO.reload(item.getDependent()));
   }

   validator.validate(form, result);

   if( result.hasErrors()){
   [...]